# Find A and B such that the limit is true

Tags: limits

The limit is

$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(x^2)(\sin(1/x))}{b-\cos(ax)} = 2 $$

I have tried to use $ \lim_{x\to 0} \sin(x)/x = 1 $ to simplify the original equation (multiplying by $ \frac{1/x}{1/x} $) to get

$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{b-\cos(ax)} = 2 $$

Using L'Hopital results in

$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{a\sin(ax)} = 2 $$

This does not seem right. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you see $\lim_{x\to 0}b-cos ax=0?$

Comment: You couldn't use L'Hôpital's rule unless you know the denominator converges to zero.

Comment: so I force the denominator to converge by setting b-1=0, or b=1?

Comment: Are you sure that it's $$\sin\dfrac1x$$

Comment: there is something missing.

Comment: it is sin(1/x), and the question does not mention any other detail

Answer (score 1):

> For all $a,b$ (except $b=1$, where the limit is indeterminant)
>   $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{(x^2)(\sin(1/x))}{b-\cos(ax)} = 0$$

A simple way to conceptualize this is to break the limit down into parts.

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}x^2=0$$

$$-1\leq\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\sin\frac{1}{x}\leq1$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0} (b-\cos ax) = b-1$$

Your limit then is then

$$\frac{(0)(-1 \text{ to } 1)}{b-1} =0 $$

Note: This is why $b$ cannot be $1$, since we are left with $(1-1)$ in the denominator

Answer (score 0):

There are no values of $a,b\ne 1$ for which this equation is true since for the above values the limit is always $0$ since the numerator has the absolute value $$x^2|\sin(1/x)|\le x^2,$$ which vanishes as $x\to 0.$

The only possibility is to check what happens when $b=1.$ In this case we have that the denominator approaches $+\infty$ as $x\to 0.$ Thus, again, the limit is in this case $0.$

So we conclude that there are no values of $a$ and $b$ which satisfy this equation.